# how to make a checkbox selected automatically?

Tags: php, html

i want to check the checkbox automatic, i tried with below code but its not checking the checkbox

**HTML**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");





$variable=$_POST['chk1'];
//print $variable;
$checkbox=implode(',',$variable);

//print $checkbox;


$sql_selectcpnn="SELECT * from clientnetworkpricehistory where id in ($checkbox)";
$querycpnn = mysql_query($sql_selectcpnn);

//print$sql_selectcpnn;



echo "<table style='margin:0px;width:364px'>
<tr>

<th>DateTime</th>
<th>By(employee)</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($querycpnn))
{ 
    $clientid=$row['clientid'];
    //print$clientid;
    $net=$row['net_id'];
    //print$net;
   $id=$row['id'];
  // print$id;

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" .date('d.m.Y H:i', $row['datetime']) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
echo"<input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value= '$id' checked='checked'/>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

can anyone tell me what would be my code to show a checkboxs as selected.thanks

Comment: You are using XHTML so you need to have checked="checked"

Comment: `echo"<input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value= '$id' checked='checked' />";` ?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you probably have something else on your page ,which you aren't showing us, that is preventing the check box from being checked. My guess would be some JavaScript. (Or you are simply looking at a cached version of the page.)

Comment: `checked="checked"` isn't it. No browser in the world (even ones that "support" XHTML) cares about that.

Comment: checked="checked" is not working

Comment: @Xavi The server-side PHP code won't help here. It's a client side problem, so you need to show us the client-side rendered HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
  echo "<input  type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' checked='checked' value= '$id' />";
```

Comment: @Xavi your table layout is preventing the checkbox from being checked, remove echo "<table style='margin:0px;width:364px'><tr><th>DateTime</th><th>By(employee)</th></tr>"; and it will start working